# Convert indices in longtensor format to binary selection mask in torch

Tags: lua, deep-learning, torch

I have a LongTensor which contains all the indices I want from another tensor.  How can I convert this LongTensor into a ByteTensor that can be used as a selection mask.

Assume,

```
th> imageLabels:size()
 17549
     3
[torch.LongStorage of size 2]

                                                                      [0.0001s]
th> indices
  1
 22
 32
[torch.LongTensor of size 3]
```

I need a way to access imageLabels using `[index]` notation so that I can change some values in imageLabels in-place.

Is there any way to do this?  As far as I understood from the docs, :index, :narrow operations return a completely new Tensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using indexFill.

targetTensor:indexFill(1, indices, 0)

- the first argument is the dimension,
- indices is the LongTensor containing all the indices we are interested in
- 0 is the value to fill.  Can be any number

Hope this helps.  Its all in the docs.  We have to read it patiently.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, :index, narrow return a new tensor, the new tensor uses the same original storage as stated in the doc [here](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md): "For methods narrow, select and sub the returned tensor shares the same Storage as the original"